# I am able to click a Navigationbarbutton item outside of the navigation bar? not a custom bar button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, xcode6

[image]

I can click 5-10 points underneath the navigationbar and it registers a button click.  This barbutton item is not a custom bar button.  I used the new debug views debugger and the frame of the barbutton item is not stretching down underneath the navigation bar.  this is not a custom navigation bar.